# Transfer Data using TCP and USB between iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, macos, tcp, app-store

I want to implement TCP data transfer between iOS and OSX . I googled and came across [Peer Talk project](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) which uses TCP to transfer data , it is working nicely , only concern i have 
is will i face any difficulties in approval from apple. as their [readME](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk/commit/bf316bf5eb785df1493a24021408697b2f7612e8) section says

> PeerTalk has successfully been released on both the iOS and OS X app stores as the driver for [DeviceSync](https://itunes.apple.com/app/devicesync-for-ios/id737867459), a simple app that copies contact data from iOS to OS X ([iOS source](https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-iOS), [OS X source](https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-OS-X)). This means that you can probably use PeerTalk for apps aiming for the App Store. Note however that there has been several reports of app submissions with PeerTalk that have been denied publication in the app stores.

Please guide me is it safe to use this or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Torn between flagging this to close as off-topic (not programming, or request for opinion and/or outside resources) and wanting to actually see the answer :)

Comment: Seems like a fair question to me... if there is a right way to do TCP over USB between Mac and iOS, it would be nice to share that.

Comment: So, did you used this in the end? Did Apple approve your apps or not?